# Как предотвратить заспамливание сайта?

Tags: php, captcha, спам

На сайте нет регистрации, но пользователи могут создавать страницы (подобно тому как это происходит на jsfiddle.net при нажатии на кнопку "Save").

Как предотвратить заспамливание сайта в этом случае? Под заспамливанием я имею ввиду автоматическое создание большого количества таких страниц.

Мои мысли по поиску решения: Выводить каждый раз капчу перед отправкой запроса на создание страницы - плохое решение. Использовать cookie для того чтобы выводить капчу с N раза так же не могу - на сайте нет регистрации, т.е. наличие cookie вообще не обязательно для отправки запроса на создание страницы. Выводить капчу по IP так же плохой вариант.

Comment: А какое отношения куки имеют к регистрации ? Они практически у всех включены, так что вполне можете отслеживать клиентов по ним. и если куки нет - то просить капчу и выдавать куку что бы в дальнейшем не просить. Правда это не спасет, никто не мешает мне один раз руками написать, заполнить капчу, получить куку, а потом запустить робота что бы он присылал ту же куку и все заголовки моего браузера.

Comment: Можно задать тяжёлую формулу на js, которая считает контрольную сумму. Желательно что б сумма считалась где-то секунду. Так же можно сделать что б контрольное число было "действительно" определённое время. И контрольное число действительно было один раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Выводить каждый раз капчу перед отправкой запроса на создание страницы - плохое решение.

Это единственное решение.

Comment: улучшу решение - нужно "запоминать" юзера (куки, сессии на сервере) и если он начинает "нарушать" - вот тогда показывать каптчи, блокировать и тому подобное. Правильно подобранные условия позволят нормальным пользователям никогда не видеть капчи.

Comment: Это абсолютно бессмысленное занятие. Следует понимать, что капча предназначена не для "хороших" юзеров, а против "плохих"

Comment: все зависит от потребностей. Я прекрасно понимаю, что юных скрипткидисов это остановит, а тех, кто пришел спамить целенаправленно нет.

Comment: @KoVadim На сайте нет регистрации => не нужны никакие куки/сесси для отправки запроса на создание страницы => я не могу отлавливать спамеров по кукам.

Comment: @Khipster ну так он предлагает их добавить. Как бы и куки и сессии можно использовать и без регистрации. Другое дело что это не имеет смысла от слова "совсем"

Comment: @Khipster куки и регистрация не связаны вообще никак. Впрочем, ни то, ни другое всё равно не поможет

Comment: Как показывать капчу не сразу? В этом весь вопрос.

Comment: @Khipster надо понимать, что здесь как с беременностью - наполовину защититься невозможно. Или показываем всем ,или имеем спам. Какой смысл показывать "не сразу", если первый же запрос будет спамом?

Comment: @Ипатьев С точки зрения UX это ужасное решение.

Comment: @Khipster а какакая разница? Других-то все равно нет. Можно конечно ходить и страдать на эту тему, но вариантов от этого не прибавится.Ну можно, действительно, пока ресурс не очень популярный, сделать тупой ханипот. Но как только сайт раскрутится, надо будет ставить нормальную капчу

Comment: @Ипатьев По-моему лучше уж горы спама чем капча для нормальных пользователей. Тот же jsfiddle.net по-моему вообще никак с таким спамом не борется, возможно потому что текст ничего не весит да и смысла особого спамить там нету - ссылки не активны и ни в какой топ эти странцы не всплывают.

Comment: @Khipster тогда непонятно, в чем вопрос

Comment: @Khipster в том же jsfiddle сохранения просто нигде не публикуются сами по себе, и проблемы спама там в принципе быть не может